# Properly aligning TextViews in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I´m developing an instant message application for an university course, similar to Whatsapp as you could guess seeing the icon in the attached screenshot :).

I have a ListFragment being populated with a custom CursorAdapter. It gives two type of views, sent messages (aligned to right) and received messages (aligned to left).

The layout for sent messages works nicely, but I cannot say the same for received messages.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Sent message layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="#FFCCCCCC"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ceo_timestamp"
            android:layout_width="60sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="#FFBBBBBB"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ceo_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ceo_timestamp"
            android:background="#FFAAAAAA"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Received message layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="#FF999999"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cei_timestamp"
            android:layout_width="60sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="#FF888888"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cei_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/cei_timestamp"
            android:background="#FF777777"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Those ugly background colors are added just to see the space taken for each view and layout. As you can see in the screenshot, send messages (right-aligned) work great. Received messages (left-aligned) aren't aligning well, because RelativeLayout takes all horizontal space available, insted of just wrapping content.

Anyone knows how to fix it, or maybe a better layout design to accomplish what I need?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: +1 for a screen shot that tells all the story... :)

Comment: those stupid things and coffee are nice to keep on when having work to do and lacking time :)

Comment: +1 for your screen shot.

Answer (score 1):

In Sent message layout replace android:layout_alignParentRight="true" parameter with the  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true".

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! I tried that, and alignments work good, but the opposite as expected. I want to get sent messages to right, and received messages to left.

Comment: So you can change the alignment of both to left and right wherever you want . :)

Answer (score 0):

When `RelativeLayout`'s child is `alignParentRight`, it's width will be auto changed to `match_parent`. `TextView` cei_timestamp 's `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` make it's parent's width change from `wrap_content` to `match_parent` silently.
U have two ways to correct:

1. do not use `RelativeLayout`

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
           android:background="#FF999999"
           android:padding="5dp" >

           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/cei_text"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:background="#FF777777"
               android:gravity="right"
               android:textSize="16sp" />

           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/cei_timestamp"
               android:layout_width="60sp"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:background="#FF888888"
               android:gravity="center"
               android:textSize="10sp" />

       </LinearLayout>

   </RelativeLayout>
   ```
2. do not use `wrap_content`, both use specific width like `60dp`.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is late but I am posting it for someone looking for the solution of same problem.
To align the received message to the left just remove this line from second TextView in xml for received messages.

```
 android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/cei_timestamp"
```

I tried it with a simple example and it worked.
Here is the code and screen shot

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.android.myapplication1.MainActivity">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FF4081">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="60sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:textSize="23sp" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="23sp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout marginTop = "104dp"
    android:text="New Button" /></RelativeLayout>`
```

[image: button is irrelevant but please tolerate it anyways :)]