# Properly adjusting space between two textviews in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-relativelayout, textview

I have been editing my relativelayout all day, but I cannot produce a screen that is desirable.

Currently it looks like this :

[image]

It is not centered and there is a very awkward space between the hour time and the minutes time.

I am trying to figure out how to fix it so it is centered similar to this app except I include the little h and m.

[image]

I have done a lot of research and used almost every positioning view in Relative Layout, but still cannot produce it.

[Properly aligning TextViews in RelativeLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9578672/properly-aligning-textviews-in-relativelayout)

This is my xml file. Not sure what to do I feel like I have exhausted all my options.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:seekarc="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/seekArcContainer"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

    </FrameLayout>

    <include
        layout="@layout/controls"
        android:id="@+id/controls" />

    <com.triggertrap.seekarc.SeekArc
        android:id="@+id/seekArc"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        seekarc:thumb="@drawable/custom_seek_arc_control_selector"
        android:padding="30dp"
        seekarc:rotation="0"
        seekarc:startAngle="0"
        seekarc:sweepAngle="360"
        seekarc:touchInside="true"
        seekarc:arcColor="#30ff5b56"
        seekarc:progressColor="#ffff3a35"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seekArcContainer"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hour_progress_number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/red_highlight"
        android:text="00"



        android:textSize="90sp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/little_hour_text2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/minute_progress_number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/red_highlight"


        android:text="00"
        android:textSize="90sp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/little_minute_text2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/hour_progress_number"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/little_minute_text2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="H"
        android:textSize="24sp"



        android:id="@+id/little_hour_text2"

        android:textColor="@color/red_highlight"

        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/minute_progress_number"
        android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/hour_progress_number"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/minute_progress_number" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="M"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:id="@+id/little_minute_text2"
        android:textColor="@color/red_highlight"

        android:layout_marginRight="36dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/seekArc"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/seekArc"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/minute_progress_number" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can the hour and minute text fields be just 1 text field? HH:MM. That way you only have to worry about centering 1 text field

Comment: Unfortunately not :(

Comment: place a dummy view in center and then hour toLeftOf and minute toRightOf that dummy view.

Comment: True. You could setup a grid view in the middle as Ketan suggested

Comment: how would I implement that?

Answer (score 1):

try this code, may this xml help you..you can take idea from this. if any problem, then ask...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp" >

        <com.triggertrap.seekarc.SeekArc
            android:id="@+id/seekArc"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="00"
                    android:textSize="60sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="H"
                    android:textSize="30sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="00"
                    android:textSize="60sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="M"
                    android:textSize="30sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

what you are looking for is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961355/percentage-width-in-a-relativelayout) in the 2nd answer (not the accepted answer). You use a strut in the middle of the two views.

this is the example given in the answer:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <View android:id="@+id/strut"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/strut"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Left"/> 
    <Button 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/strut"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Right"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```